# Tetrads and metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, mathematical-physics, differential-forms

I'm looking to do a similar calculation as in: [Curvature tensor of 2-sphere using exterior differential forms (tetrads)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410844/curvature-tensor-of-2-sphere-using-exterior-differential-forms-tetrads)

in terms of tetrads/Vierbeins etc but I can't find any literature on *how* one explicitly calculates the tetrads or even what they are. Any help or clarity would be greatly appreciated. Even if you could explain how to calculate this tetrad basis $e^\theta = rd\theta$ and $e^\phi = r \sin{\theta} d\phi$ in this case.

Any references on the Riemann curvature tensor in terms of tetrads and the torsion tensor would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From modern treatment, you can try [$\textit{Curvature in Mathematics and Physics}$ by S. Sternberg Chapter 6](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486478556.html). Plus there are some practical calculations at the end of the chapter. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is covered extremely well in [John Stewart's Advanced General Relativity](http://Stewart,%20J.%20(1991).%20Spinors.%20In%20Advanced%20General%20Relativity%20(Cambridge%20Monographs%20on%20Mathematical%20Physics,%20pp.%2062-112).%20Cambridge:%20Cambridge%20University%20Press.%20doi:10.1017/CBO9780511608179.003). It is a short textbook but extremely rich in content, certainly on the tetrad representation moving to Newman-Penrose formalism.

Alternatively you could look in the introduction / Chapter 1 of [Chandrasekhar's Mathematical Theory of Black Holes](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-009-6469-3_2).